# user input still stored after exceeding array length

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Can someone see why the user can enter more than 27 apple, blueberry, or peanut pies? Even after declaring a final int for the max number of each type of pie.

The object here is to continually prompt the user for type of pie until the user wants to quit. Each time one of the valid inputs is entered it is stored in it's own array. After the user has indicated they are finished, calculations are done and a message is printed.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CalcPieProfit {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      final int MAX_PER_TYPE = 27; 

      int appleTotal = 0;
      int blueberryTotal = 0;
      int peanutTotal = 0;

      String typeOfPie = getPieType();
      while (!typeOfPie.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
         if (typeOfPie.equalsIgnoreCase("apple")) {
            String[] appleArray = fillApple(typeOfPie, MAX_PER_TYPE);
            appleTotal++;
         }
         else if (typeOfPie.equalsIgnoreCase("blueberry")) {
            String[] blueberryArray = fillBlueberry(typeOfPie, MAX_PER_TYPE);
            blueberryTotal++;
         }
         else if (typeOfPie.equalsIgnoreCase("peanut")) {
            String[] peanutArray = fillPeanut(typeOfPie, MAX_PER_TYPE);
            peanutTotal++;
         }
         typeOfPie = getPieType();
      }

      if (typeOfPie.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
         int totalPies = calcTotalPies(appleTotal, blueberryTotal, peanutTotal);
         double profit = calcProfit(appleTotal, blueberryTotal, peanutTotal);
         printReport(totalPies, appleTotal, blueberryTotal, peanutTotal, profit);

      }

   }

   public static String getPieType() {

      String pieType;

      do {     
         try {

            pieType = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a pie type:");        
         }         
         catch (NumberFormatException e) {         
            pieType = "";         
         }      
         if (!pieType.equalsIgnoreCase("apple") && !pieType.equalsIgnoreCase("blueberry") &&
         !pieType.equalsIgnoreCase("peanut") && !pieType.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {        
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter 'apple', 'blueberry', 'peanut', or 'q' only.");        
         }     
      } while (!pieType.equalsIgnoreCase("apple") && !pieType.equalsIgnoreCase("blueberry") &&
      !pieType.equalsIgnoreCase("peanut") && !pieType.equalsIgnoreCase("q"));

      return pieType;

   }

   public static String[] fillApple(String typeOfPie, int MAX_PER_TYPE) {

      String[] appleArray = new String[MAX_PER_TYPE];

      for (int i = 0; i < appleArray.length; i++) {

         appleArray[i] = typeOfPie;

      }

      return appleArray;

   }

   public static String[] fillBlueberry(String typeOfPie, int MAX_PER_TYPE) {

      String[] blueberryArray = new String[MAX_PER_TYPE];

      for (int i = 0; i < blueberryArray.length; i++) {

         blueberryArray[i] = typeOfPie;

      }

      return blueberryArray;

   }

   public static String[] fillPeanut(String typeOfPie, int MAX_PER_TYPE) {

      String[] peanutArray = new String[MAX_PER_TYPE];

      for (int i = 0; i < peanutArray.length; i++) {

         peanutArray[i] = typeOfPie;

      }

      return peanutArray;

   }

   public static int calcTotalPies(int appleTotal, int blueberryTotal, int peanutTotal) {

      int total = appleTotal + blueberryTotal + peanutTotal;

      return total;

   }

   public static double calcProfit (int appleTotal, int blueberryTotal, int peanutTotal) {

      final double APPLE_PROFIT = 5.94;
      final double BLUEBERRY_PROFIT = 5.89;
      final double PEANUT_PROFIT = 6.95;

      double profit = (APPLE_PROFIT * appleTotal) + (BLUEBERRY_PROFIT * blueberryTotal) + 
         (PEANUT_PROFIT * peanutTotal);

      return profit;

   }

   public static void printReport(int totalPies, int appleTotal, int blueberryTotal, int peanutTotal, double profit) {

      if (totalPies > 0) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "Pie Report\n\n" +
            "Total pies: " + totalPies +
            "\nTotal of apple pie: " + appleTotal +
            "\nTotal of blueberry pie: " + blueberryTotal +
            "\nTotal of peanut butter pie: " + peanutTotal +
            "\nTotal profit: $" + String.format("%.2f", profit));
      }
      else {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enjoy your day off.");
      }

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not really using the `String[]`s `appleArray`, `blueberryArray` and `peanutArray` - they are created in their respective method but not used anywhere else. For calculating the profits, you are (rightfully) only the total variables.

Instead of

```
if (typeOfPie.equalsIgnoreCase("apple")) {
    String[] appleArray = fillApple(typeOfPie, MAX_PER_TYPE);
    appleTotal++;
}
```

you should do something like

```
if (typeOfPie.equalsIgnoreCase("apple")) {
    if (appleTotal >= MAX_PER_TYPE) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Too many apples.");
    } else {
        appleTotal++;
    }
}
```

(and the same for other pie types).

Comment: Hmm how could I use the String[] s to keep track of the totals instead of using ++

Comment: It's possible, but you shouldn't, as arrays have a fixed length. Use [`List`s](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/list.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're redeclaring the pie arrays each time you go to add them.

```
public static String[] fillApple(String typeOfPie, int MAX_PER_TYPE) {
    String[] appleArray = new String[MAX_PER_TYPE];
    for (int i = 0; i < appleArray.length; i++) {
        appleArray[i] = typeOfPie;
    }
    return appleArray;
}
```

Each time you call this method, a new "appleArray" is generated.  If you want it to persist between calls to this method, declare the appleArray as private static outside of the loop, and reference that instead.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused.. can you show me an example?